# Why do I get java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: android.app.alarmmanager$alarmclockinfo?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, runtime-error, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make an application that sets an alarm at a given time using AlarmManager, BrodcastReceiver and AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo to set the alarm. But everytime I run it, I got this error message.

To sum up, I want an alarm ringing in 20 seconds. This my MainActivity code (views injected with ButterKnife):

```
@InjectView(R.id.alarmTimePicker) TimePicker timePicker;
@InjectView(R.id.alarmText) TextView tv_texto;
@InjectView(R.id.alarmToggle) ToggleButton tg_toggle;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void onToggleClicked (View view){
    if (tg_toggle.isChecked()){
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 20);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("warning", "The alarm is ringing.");

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, pendingIntent);
    }else
        //Do other stuff
}
```

And then there is the AlarmReceiver class extending BradcastReceiver and its declaration as a `<receiver>` in the manifest. But the error refers to the line `AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmClockInfo = new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);`.

Here's the full error log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.AlarmManager$AlarmClockInfo
            at examen.melerogomez.clock.MainActivity.onToggleClicked(MainActivity.java:64)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the complete exception logs

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo class was added in API 21 and I was trying to run it in a emulator with API 19 and `minsdkversion 15`.